# how can I access a pagetitle Component attribute in app.html template

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In ionic (3.20) if you start your app with the sidemenu template with `ionic start myApp sidemenu`, you end up with two pages (list and home). Each page template contains an ion-header that contains the ion-navbar. This means that changes to the navbar need to be made to every page individually. I am moving this to the app.html template so the navbar is the same everywhere. So this is what my app.html looks like:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{pagetitle}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="flase"></ion-nav>
```

Now the problem I am having is with the pagetitle attribute. Each page will have this attribute defined, but how do I access it from the app.html template?

Right now my page/home/home.ts looks like this (the FieldService is irrelevant in this case):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { FieldService } from '../../app/field.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [FieldService]
})
export class HomePage {
  fields: any[];
  pagetitle: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, service: FieldService) {
    this.fields = service.getFields();
    this.pagetitle = "Home";
  }

}
```

but with this setup, the pagetitle does not appear in the actual page. I guess in the app.html page the component attribute "pagetitle" is not available.

Comment: is the ion-menu inside `home.html`? because your `HomePage` is using `home.html` as its template html, *not* `app.html`

Comment: No that is the whole point. Home.html is only for the home page. I want the menu for all pages, not just the home page. So indeed it is in app.html, which is the template for the app controller. I guess I need to do something with the Nav part of it to communicate the page title property between the page component and the app component.

Comment: I understand. Take a look at my answer, and see if it is something you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### METHOD 1

You could listen for url-changes inside your `AppComponent`, and set the pagetitle according to the url.

in your constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
         if(event.url.matches('home')){
             this.pagetitle = 'Home';
         }else if(event.url.matches('somethingElse')){
             this.pagetitle = 'Something else';
         }
      }
    });
  }
```

### METHOD 2

Another method is to create a shared service, set the pagetitle there, and use it inside your ion-menu.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {
  pagetitle: string;
  constructor() { }
}
```

and then use it inside your AppComponent

```
constructor(public headerService: HeaderService) { //must be public!
}
```

and in your html instead of writing {{pagetitle}}, write {{headerService.pagetitle}}

then inside your `HomePage`, and other components, set the pagetitle.

```
export class HomePage {
  fields: any[];
  pagetitle: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, service: FieldService, private headerService: HeaderService) {
    this.fields = service.getFields();
    this.headerService.pagetitle = "Home";
  }

}
```

**NOTE:** Code is not tested

Comment: Hmm, method 2 sounds promising. I will test in a bit.